# Populate Popup Modal with information matching from list to user signed into SharePoint

Tags: modal-dialog, sharepoint-online

I have a custom list that has a custom edit.aspx form which is attached to a modal popup form.  My issues is I need to be able to find the matching record in the list of 1300 people that is associated to person who is signed into the SharePoint site.  I do not want then having access to the main list we just want them to click a button on the home page it populates the information with the person authenticated and they fill out two fields and click save and it returns them back to the home page.  They never go to the main list at all.  I have everything working as expected up to pulling the information from the list into the form.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Dorinda

Answer (score 0):

We can create a html button and popup a dialog using JSOM code.

To get the list item URL from main list of the current user, we can use jQuery with REST API to filter the list items in main list by the current user. Then build the URL, and then open a popup dialog.

References:

[Get list items created by logged in user with REST api](http://Get%20list%20items%20created%20by%20logged%20in%20user%20with%20REST%20api)

[How to Create a Pop-Up Dialog in SharePoint?](http://sharethepunto.blogspot.sg/2014/06/how-to-create-pop-up-dialog.html)